# Ember simple-auth-token won't whitelist API server

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I've missed; I'm using the `simple-auth` and `simple-auth-token` libraries (via `ember-cli 0.2.3`) and can't seem to get my app to set the appropriate `Athentication:` HTTP header. From what I've read, the most common oversight is people not setting the `crossOriginWhitelist:` property on the `simple-auth` ENV variable. However, even with a value of `['*']`, I can't seem to get Ember to send the headers with my API requests. Mind you, I'm replacing a previous hand-rolled (though, half-baked!) auth solution, so I know my API server works and *will* authenticate, given the right credentials.

When I run the `login` action everything works flawlessly. If I hit a protected Ember route after that, it works fine as well. The problem comes when `Ember-data` tries to hit my API (at `http://localhost:3000`); it gets back a `401` (since it didn't set the `Authorization:` header) and transitions to the index of my site.

Here's the relevant sections of code:

**config/environments.js**

```
...

ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authenticationRoute: 'login',
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token',
    crossOriginWhitelist: ['*']
};
ENV['simple-auth-token'] = {
    identificationField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    tokenPropertyName: 'token',
    authorizationPrefix: 'Bearer ',
    authorizationHeaderName: 'Authorization'
};
...
```

**routes/login.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    login: function(){
      var creds = this.controller.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:jwt', creds)
        .then(function() {
          // +
          }, function() {
          // -
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**routes/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/environment.js`, try to add:

```
var ENV = {
  ...
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    'default-src': "'none'",
    'script-src': "'self'",
    'font-src': "'self'",
    'connect-src': "'self' *",
    'img-src': "'self'",
    'style-src': "'self'",
    'media-src': "'self'"
  }
  ...
};
```

Comment: No dice, sadly. Could it be that my server just isn't sending the data back in a properly formatted way? It seems to be storing it in localstorage just fine—moreover, the key is set to `token` just as one would expect.

Comment: Well, for the time being, I've just referenced the value in localStorage directly in my adapter and set the headers there.